# issues with a bone and weight paint not changing mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

so ive been trying to rig this bow and ive ran into an issue currently and ive tried lots of stuff to sort it out and im still struggling.

The string of the bow when pulled back pulls a block of the string rather than a single point like a real bow would.

Ive tried painting the weight manually but that section of the string is only effected by either min or max weights nothing inbetween.

any help would be great its been driving me mad!

[.blend is here](https://file.io/1x7Zy7W6LImU)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the vertices at the center are part of only one group and in that case, even if they are part of this group at a weight of 0.1, the bone will act as if it has an influence of 1, thus the straight part where you have all these said vertices.

To fix that you could remove the vertices all along the rope except at center:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

If for some reason you need to keep all these vertices along the rope then you'll need a bit more complicated setup, you'll need to create additional bones that will share the influence on these vertices with the string bone.

Comment: This solved it!! Thanks I didnt realise this happened! I originally only put in more vertices to see if it would fix this issue as it had a lot less!